# Twig Relationship with extra columns

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem and don't know the best practice to solve it.

I want to have a form for my core data. The core data is all versionable.
I solved it with a GUID, to know the togetherness of the versions.

So now I have two versionable entities `AgeClass` and `HighscoreList` that can have a many-to-many relationship. The relationship has to be versionable, too, so I created a `ReferenceEntity` `RefAgeClassHighscoreList`. Now I have relationships with extra columns

> valid-from [and]
>   valid-to

But now I don't know how I should build my form.
When I edit an `AgeClass`, all current (valid) `HighscoreList` items should be show as a checkbox.
But when I build the edit form, the values must be bound with a `RefAgeClassHighscoreList` entity.

I hope you understand my problem.

AgeClass:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DSV\Core\BaseDSVCoreDataRepository")
 * */
class AgeClass extends BaseDSVCoreData
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @NotBlank()
     * @var int
     */
    protected $minAge;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @NotBlank()
     * @var int
     */
    protected $maxAge;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RefAgeClassHighscoreList", mappedBy="ageClass", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var PersistentCollection
     */
    private $ageClassHighscoreLists;

    /**
     * AgeClass constructor.
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setGuid(GuidHelper::generateGuid());
        $this->setValidFrom(new \DateTime());
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMinAge()
    {
        return $this->minAge;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $minAge
     * @return AgeClass
     */
    public function setMinAge($minAge)
    {
        $this->minAge = $minAge;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxAge()
    {
        return $this->maxAge;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $maxAge
     * @return AgeClass
     */
    public function setMaxAge($maxAge)
    {
        $this->maxAge = $maxAge;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAgeClassHighscoreLists()
    {
        if($this->ageClassHighscoreLists == null)
            return array();
        return $this->ageClassHighscoreLists->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param PersistentCollection $valuationClasses
     * @return AgeClass
     */
    public function seAgeClassHighscoreLists($valuationClasses)
    {
        $this->ageClassHighscoreLists = $valuationClasses;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return HighscoreList[]
     */
    public function getHighscoreLists()
    {
        return array_map(
            function ($ageClassHighscoreList) {
                /** @var RefAgeClassHighscoreList $ageClassHighscoreList */
                return $ageClassHighscoreList->getHighscoreList();
            },
            $this->getAgeClassHighscoreLists()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param RefAgeClassHighscoreList $ageClassHighscoreList
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAgeClassHighscoreList($ageClassHighscoreList)
    {
        if (!$this->ageClassHighscoreLists->contains($ageClassHighscoreList)) {
            $this->ageClassHighscoreLists->add($ageClassHighscoreList);
            $ageClassHighscoreList->setAgeClass($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

HighscoreList

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DSV\Core\BaseDSVCoreDataRepository")
 * */
class HighscoreList extends BaseDSVCoreData
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RefAgeClassHighscoreList", mappedBy="highscoreList", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var PersistentCollection
     */
    private $ageClassHighscoreLists;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setGuid(GuidHelper::generateGuid());
    }

    /**
     * @return PersistentCollection
     */
    public function getAgeClassReferences()
    {
        return $this->ageClassHighscoreLists;
    }

    /**
     * @param PersistentCollection $valuationClasses
     * @return AgeClass
     */
    public function setAgeClassReferences($valuationClasses)
    {
        $this->ageClassReferences = $valuationClasses;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return AgeClass[]
     */
    public function getAgeClasses()
    {
        return array_map(
            function ($ageClassHighscoreList) {
                /** @var RefAgeClassHighscoreList $ageClassHighscoreList */
                return $ageClassHighscoreList->getAgeClass();
            },
            $this->ageClassHighscoreLists->toArray()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param RefAgeClassHighscoreList $ageClassHighscoreList
     * @return HighscoreList
     */
    public function addAgeClassReference($ageClassHighscoreList)
    {
        if (!$this->ageClassHighscoreLists->contains($ageClassHighscoreList)) {
            $this->ageClassHighscoreLists->add($ageClassHighscoreList);
            $ageClassHighscoreList->setHighscoreList($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

}

RefAgeClassHighscoreList

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * */
class RefAgeClassHighscoreList implements IVersionable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $validFrom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $validTo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AgeClass", inversedBy="highscoreListReferences")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ageclass_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $ageClass;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="highscoreList", inversedBy="ageClassReferences")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="highscorelist_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $highscoreList;

    protected $hasChanges = false;

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function getGuid()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function setGuid($guid)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function getValidFrom()
    {
        return $this->validFrom;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function setValidFrom($validFrom)
    {
        $this->validFrom = $validFrom;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function getValidTo()
    {
        return $this->validTo;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function setValidTo($validTo)
    {
        $this->validTo = $validTo;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        return ($this->validTo == null);
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function createNewVersion()
    {
        $newVersion = clone $this;
        $newVersion->setValidFrom(new \DateTime());

        return $newVersion;
    }

    /**
     * @see IVersionable
     */
    public function hasChanges()
    {
        return $this->hasChanges;
    }

    /**
     * @return AgeClass
     */
    public function getAgeClass()
    {
        return $this->ageClass;
    }

    /**
     * @param AgeClass $ageClass
     * @return RefAgeClassHighscoreList
     */
    public function setAgeClass($ageClass)
    {
        $this->ageClass = $ageClass;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return HighscoreList
     */
    public function getHighscoreList()
    {
        return $this->highscoreList;
    }

    /**
     * @param HighscoreList $highscoreList
     * @return RefAgeClassHighscoreList
     */
    public function setHighscoreList($highscoreList)
    {
        $this->gighscoreList = $highscoreList;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a very recurrent and tedious problem. You can do an [embed form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) with AgeClass and embedding a form for RefAgeClassHighscoreList type. In that embedded form you can have an attribute of type HighscoreList , the problem is that the default rendered component for what you need is a multi-select list of HighscoreList, you can see it putting the attribute multiple = true to the property of HighscoreList.

For transform that list to a check-box list you need to create a custom [theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) extending or adding new blocks to the default one provided by symfony. My advice is to create new widgets and rows for your specific form using the form name. You can find a lot of documentation about what I mention and need to get a small part of each one to do what you ask.

Hope all this clues help you.